# How do I make the Chrome browser pop into focus for alerts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have an application in Chrome App Mode running on Windows. The user will be using other applications as well but if there is an alert in the Chrome app, I want that browser window to popup on top of all the other windows so that the user can see the alert. I assume this type of thing was intentionally removed (if it ever existed) due to abuse by ads and things like that but I can't think of any way to alert the user without a separate windows app.

Comment: I'm not sure it ever existed in Chrome, nut have you looked att [Notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)? It is used to give the user a notification in the notification tray.

Comment: That might be a good workaround but then I saw this note: "going forward browsers will explicitly disallow notifications not triggered in response to a user gesture".

Comment: That is a restriction for ***requesting*** the permission to send notifications, not for actually sending notifications. If you examine `Notification.permission` and it is `granted` the user have already given you permission to send notifications. It would be a pretty useless function if the user had to press a button before every notification. The restriction exists to prevent websites to ask for permissions just by loading the page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that feature has ever existed in Chrome. If I remember correctly it was possible to do in Netscape in the mid 1990s, at least you could move and resize the window. Of course, it didn't take long before that functionality was abused and therefore removed.

[window.focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus) is intended to bring the window to the foreground but whether it works depends on whether the browser supports it and the user has allowed it. In my limited testing with Chrome and Firefox, I couldn't get it to work, despite giving the site all possible permissions.

Since in some cases there are legitimate reasons to alert the user that something has happened in a window that does not have focus, there is now a [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification), which uses the operating system's mechanism to display the message. It works on both computers and mobile devices.

The default setting in most browsers is that the user must actively choose to accept notifications from the website. This only needs to be done once, as the browser remembers the answer.

If the user has given permission once, it's just a matter of sending as many notifications as you deem necessary, without the user having to do anything.

```
// Example of how to request permission
async function requestNotificationPermission() {
  // Feature detection: is Notification available?
  if ('Notification' in window) {
    const permission = await Notification.requestPermission();
    if (permission === 'granted') {
      console.log('Permission granted!');
    }
  }
}

// Example of how to send a notification
function sendNotification(message) {
  // Feature detection: is Notification available?
  if ('Notification' in window) {
    // If permission is 'granted' we are allowed to send notifications.
    if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
      const notification = new Notification(message);
    }
  }
}

// Example of how to add an event listener to a button with id 'myNotifyButton'
document.getElementById('myNotifyButton').addEventListener('click', requestNotificationPermission);

// Example of how to send a notification 10 seconds after page load
setTimeout(() => sendNotification('My notification!'), 10000);
```